# php static variable initialization using the $this keyword

Tags: php, variables, static, initialization

I'm having a method inside a class, in which I want to initialize a static variable.

1/ when I initialize the variable, then affect it to some other value using the `$this` keyword, it works. E.g.:

```
class Test {
   // ...
   function test($input_variable)
   {
      static $my_static_variable = null;
      if (!isset($my_static_variable))
        $my_static_variable = $this->someFunction($input_variable);
      // ... some further processing 
   }
}
```

2/ However, when I try to directly initialize / construct the variable with the `$this` keyword, there is a syntax error : `unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`:

```
class Test {
       // ...
       function test($input_variable)
       {
          static $my_static_variable = $this->someFunction($input_variable); // *** syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)
          // ... some further processing 
       }
}
```

Is 1/ a good way to initialize a static variable?
Why is 2/ not allowed, as it is supposed to do the exact same thing than in 1/?

I'm using PHP 5.5.21 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2016 08:31:09).

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to use a static variable in a class method? Use a class property instead: `protected $my_static_variable;` and then use `$this->my_static_variable = $this->someFunction();`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I want to use a static variable, so its value is retained between each call.

Comment: The value will be retained in a class property as well. The upside with using a class property is that you can access the variable from other methods as well, or is that what you don't want?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes, you are right. I have written an explanation below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$this` on a static variable. You can use `self` with scope resolution operator (::) instead.

Here is the example:

```
class Foo {
  public static $my_stat;

  static function init() {
    self::$my_stat= 'My val';
  }
}
```

Comment: Having `static $variable;` in a function/method is not the same as static class properties.

Answer (score 0):

Static variable and function can be accessed without instantiation of the class. You can not use $this to access the variable or function declared as static.
You have to use scope resolution operator:: to access variable and functions declared as static.

For variables:-

```
class A
{
    static $my_static = 'foo';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;// Try to use $this here insted of self:: you will get error
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function fooStatic() {
        return parent::$my_static;
    }
}
```

Use to the following to access the variable:-

```
print A::$my_static
```

For functions:-

```
class A {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can call the function as follows:-

```
A::aStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Having `static $variable;` in a function/method is not the same as static class members.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer. In the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static), it is stated the following:

> Static variables may be declared as seen in the examples above. From
>   PHP 5.6 you can assign values to these variables which are the result
>   of expressions, **but you can't use any function here, what will cause a
>   parse error**.

So I guess this also holds for PHP 5.5.

As @MagnusEriksson pointed out, I could have used a class property as well. However, I don't want my variable to be accessed somewhere else apart from the `test()` method.

BTW, somehow the same thing is stated for static properties in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> **Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the
>   arrow operator ->.**
>
> **Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or constant before PHP 5.6; expressions
>   are not allowed**. In PHP 5.6 and later, the same rules apply as const
>   expressions: some limited expressions are possible, provided they can
>   be evaluated at compile time.